# How to turn a Map<List<K>, List<V>> into a Map<K, List<V>>?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

In a part of a code I have the situation, the type of the collection is that I need:

```
Map<Specialization, List<SpecialistInfo>> specialistsMap = specialistsResponse
    .getSpecialists()
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(SpecialistInfo::getSpecializations));
```

But actually, that stream returns a `Map<List<Specialization>, List<SpecialistInfo>>.`

The `getSpecialists()` method returns `List<SpecialistInfo> specialists;`and every instance of `SpecialistInfo` contains a list too. So, the method getSpecializations returns `List<Specialization> specializations`

I need to group my map into a `Map<Specialization, List<SpecialistInfo>>`.

How it can be done via Stream API?

Comment: You want to duplicate the data ? Like for Specialization fom the same list relate the same list of values ?

Comment: I didn't test this out, but I'm curious if it's possible with `.collect(Collectors.flatMapping(specialistInfo -> specialistInfo.getSpecializations().stream(), Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())));`

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the input datastructure contains. Is `Specialization` unique over all lists used as key in the map? Does the value `List<SpezialistInfo> belong to all Spezialization of the key list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a `List<SpecialistInfo>` and each `SpecialistInfo` has a `List<Specialization>`. You need to reverse map these. Presumably, then, `Specialization` and `SpecialistInfo` are unique and there exists a many-to-many relation between `Specializations` and `SpecialistInfo`.

If you're looking for a solution not using the streams API which is thread-safe (compared to the solution of YCF_L)

```java
List<SpecialistInfo> specialists = getSpecialists();
Map<Specialization, List<SpecialistInfo>> specMap = new HashMap<>();
for (SpecialistInfo specInfo : specialists) { 
    for (Specialization spec : specInfo.getSpecializations()) {
        specMap.computeIfAbsent(spec, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(specInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have an exception "cannot inner functional interface type"

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin My bad, I wrote that without compiling it first. Serves me right... I've amended the answer, hope that helps!